# Remove nested bbcode style tags and anything inside them

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I need help with a regex to remove some thing. I can't get it to work as I want.

Lets say I have this text:

```
[quote=test]
[quote=test]for sure[/quote]
Test
[/quote]

[this should not be removed]
Dont remove me
```

How can I remove everything above `[this should not be removed]`? Please note that `Test` can be anything.

So I want to remove anything inside:

```
[quote=*][/quote]
```

I've come this far:

```
preg_replace('#\[quote=(.+)](.+)\[/quote]#Usi', '', $message);
```

But it keeps: `Test [/quote]`

Comment: What about - `\[quote=.*\][\s\S]*\[\/quote\]` - https://regex101.com/r/qQ8iE2/1

Comment: Do you want to remove the entire line or just what is in between the tags?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the [quote=][/quote] tags and everything inside

Comment: @JoshCrozier i get the same result, which is weird as it works on that site

Comment: @Jorm I just tested it out, and it works [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c73d0a5f737d479e00b0b0e00f7f70f719794081)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching nested bbcode style code is rather complex - usually involving a non-regular expression based string parser.

Seems you are using PHP it does support the regular expression `(?R)` syntax for ["recursion"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) using this we can support nested bbcode like this.

Note that non-matching opening `[quote=*]` and closing `[/quote]` pairs will not be matched.

### Regular Expression

```
\[(quote)=[^]]+\](?>(?R)|.)*?\[/quote]
```

https://regex101.com/r/xF3oR6/1

### Code

```
$result = preg_replace('%\[(quote)=[^]]+\](?>(?R)|.)*?\[/quote]%si', '', $subject);
```

### Human Readable

```
# \[(quote)=[^]]+\](?>(?R)|.)*?\[/quote]
# 
# Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot matches line breaks; ^$ don’t match at line breaks; Greedy quantifiers; Regex syntax only
# 
# Match the character “[” literally «\[»
# Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(quote)»
#    Match the character string “quote” literally (case insensitive) «quote»
# Match the character “=” literally «=»
# Match any character that is NOT a “]” «[^]]+»
#    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
# Match the character “]” literally «\]»
# Match the regular expression below; do not try further permutations of this group if the overall regex fails (atomic group) «(?>(?R)|.)*?»
#    Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
#    Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «(?R)»
#       Match the entire regular expression (recursion; restore capturing groups upon exit; do not try further permutations of the recursion if the overall regex fails) «(?R)»
#    Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «.»
#       Match any single character «.»
# Match the character “[” literally «\[»
# Match the character string “/quote]” literally (case insensitive) «/quote]»
```

Comment: As an update to this, I just wanted to mention this regex "\[(quote)(?:=*[^]]*)\](?>(?R)|.)*?\[\/quote]" -> will fix it for when quotes don't have a =username inside :) https://regex101.com/r/Qfs6mg/1